# Implementing a slide animation in jQuery Mobile triggered by various events

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, animation, transition, slide

I've implemented a jQuery mobile footer nav with the Html below.

```
<div data-role="navbar" id="footer-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="nav1" href="">Nav 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav2" href="">Nav 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have it set up so that various events show and hide the this using the the code below:

```
$("#footer-nav").show();
$("#footer-nav").hide();
```

This works great but it just appears and disappears. Does anyone know how to have it slide in and out using a slide transition animation instead?

Comment: Yes I do. Much thanks. If you want to put that as an answer I'll certainly accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer with another option if you wanna take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SlideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) for the effect that you are looking for.

Here i am making the div slideUp in the `complete` callback of slideDown animation so that this executes after the slideDown animation is complete.

Ex:-

```
$("#footer-nav").slideDown(1000, function(){
   $(this).slideUp(1000);
});
```

you can use delay(1000) in between if you want to have a delay between actions.

```
$("#footer-nav").slideDown(1000, function(){
   $(this).delay(1000).slideUp(1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7XAys/)

Another way you can do this by using [.show()](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/) and .[hide()](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) ui effects.

#### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/bB6eT/)

```
$('#footer-nav').show("slide", {
    direction: "up"
}, 1000, function () {

    $(this).delay(1000).hide("slide", {
        direction: "up"
    }, 1000);

});
```